# Web Scraping: How to scrape the lazy loading data with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, lazy-loading

I wanted to scrape the item information from Sephora
Because of the lazy loading setting, I could only got 12 items on that page.
I already searched other questions on stackoverflow but couldn't understand what they are saying. I have little knowledge about HTML or JAVA so...please could anyone help me with how to overcome the lazy loading with R?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
url = 'https://www.sephora.com/shop/skin-care-solutions'

http_type(GET(url))
resp = read_html(url)
html_nodes(resp, css = '.css-ix8km1') %>% html_attr('href')
```

This is the code I used. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That URL bounces me straight to the sephora.fr French home page, perhaps because I'm not in the same country as you. Is it the same as this: https://www.sephora.fr/shop/soin-visage-c303/

Comment: Bonjour, Spacedman:-) I can't read French but I think it's the same page. I'm going to gather all the items of the basic skin care cosmetics and skin care solution section is one of them. The picture above is the page of 'Shop By Concern' but doesn't matter. Others like 'Moisturizers', 'Cleansers' or anything ok. Please help!